# Python aiogram handler ссылающися на другой handler

Tags: python, aiogram, handlers

Доброго времени суток.

да бы не плодить DRY как сделать так что данный handler можно было вызвать из другого callback кнопкой?

```
async def handler_one(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
for el in await see_count('one'):
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(f"{str(el[0][2:6])}", callback_data=f'{el[0]}'))
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'текст', reply_markup=markup)
```

возможно такое?

Answer (score 0):

нашел решение в

```
dp.register_handlers_others(...)
```